# Using latex to mark squares in diagrams for Killer Chess Training homework club?

Tags: chess

Killer Chess Training is a chess training website.

They give out worksheets every week like https://p8e5c7t2.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Friendly-Homework-23-%E2%80%93-2021-03-23.pdf and ask for responses in PDF which are marked.

They ask students to do three things:

- Mark weaknesses with green squares (alternate: mark with circle)
- Mark the worst placed piece(s) on both sides with yellow squares (alternate: mark with square)
- Indicate the opponent’s idea with red arrows

Is there a latex package that allows marking up chess diagrams in this way?

Comment: You could check the ‘chessboard’ package.

Comment: assuming that they give you a pdf and you have to add annotations then using a pdf reader like adobe is probably the easiest. Doing it with latex would need much measuring to get the positions correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in Latex. (You could do all this also with an image editor like Paint.net etc.)

#### Basic idea

- make a screenshot of the page of interest, save as e.g. `pg3.png` (e.g. via your viewers tools)
- use `Tikz` to enable all those drawings
- load the image into a nodes text field
- draw whatever you need over it (see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz))

#### Relevant code lines

To read the image and to show it in a tikzpicture you load it into a `\node`. Think of using the node as a medium for typesetting more complex content here. // Package `graphicx` provide `\includegraphics`, see its documentation here [at ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

```
    % ~~~ read and show pg3.png ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     pin node to its upper left corner (= north west)
    \node[anchor=north west] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pg3}};
```

Draw some colored lines, which you remove later, to get a feel for the absolute positions:

```
        % ~~~ some lines for orientation // comment out later ~~~~~~
        \draw[blue]       (0,  0) -- (13 ,0);   % now referenced to north west
        \draw[red,dashed] (0, -5) -- (13,-5);
...
```

Finally place two nodes and draw a line with an arrow tip to indicate what the exercises ask for; use some trials to find positions, which works quickly and precise enough:

```
    % ~~~ examples for indications: ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[weak] at (2.9,-1.6) {};
    \node[wrst] at (1.5,-4.2) {};
    \draw[idea]                 (1.5,-2) -- (2.5,-3);
```

To support all this define a few styles in the beginning, which:

- specify color
- shape
- line width
- minimum size (a bit larger makes placement easier)

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[   % defining some styles
    weak/.style={draw=green,shape=rectangle,
                 line width=1.5pt,minimum size=5mm},
    wrst/.style={draw=yellow,shape=rectangle,
                 line width=2pt,minimum size=5mm},
    idea/.style={draw=red,->},
 ]
```

This leads to e.g.:

[image: preliminary]

#### Approaching positions

- use the colored lines for a first estimate of coordinates
- compile and refine
- if you want to measure positions e.g. on paper, measure the nodes/squares/lines center

#### Final code

After deleting or commenting out the colored help lines:

[image: final]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}              % reads in pdf-pages
\usepackage{tikz}                   % to "draw" things
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}   % for the square

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[   % defining some styles
    weak/.style={draw=green,shape=rectangle,
                 line width=1.5pt,minimum size=5mm},
    wrst/.style={draw=yellow,shape=rectangle,
                 line width=2pt,minimum size=5mm},
    idea/.style={draw=red,->},
 ]
    % ~~~ read and show pg3.png ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     pin node to its upper left corner (= north west)
    \node[anchor=north west] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pg3}};

%       % ~~~ some lines for orientation // comment out later ~~~~~~
%       \draw[blue]       (0,  0) -- (13 ,0);   % now referenced to north west
%       \draw[red,dashed] (0, -5) -- (13,-5);
%       \draw[red,dashed] (0,-10) -- (13,-10);
%       \draw[red,dashed] (0,-15) -- (13,-15);
%
%       \draw[orange,dashed] (4,0) -- (4,-15);
%       \draw[orange,dashed] (6.5,0) -- (6.5,-15);
    
    % ~~~ examples for indications: ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[weak] at (2.9,-1.6) {};
    \node[wrst] at (1.5,-4.2) {};
    \draw[idea]                 (1.5,-2) -- (2.5,-3);

 \end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

#### A possible alternative

You could also load dedicated pdf-pages to use in Latex. However, `\includepdf` doesn't seem to work inside a `\node`, so I switched to the screenshot approach. The following shows the same page, in higher quality of course.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}   % reads in pdf-pages

\begin{document}
    % ~~~ show just page 3 ~~~~~~
    \includepdf[pages=3]{homework}  
\end{document}
```